# Jquery is not loading from Joomla module

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla-module

I have a module in joomla that uses component's view files.

The Module Code is:

```
//Html
<?php

JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
$js = " // jquery custom function and events";
$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);

?>
```

And I call module in this way:

```
<?php
            jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
            $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('module_name');
            echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
?>
```

My problem is  when I render module in view, that time html shows and works correct but jquery does not load (which means jquery not showing in console)

Thanks

Comment: which files have you put each code snippet in?

Comment: i have put module render code in component/.../tmpl/.../default.php

Comment: It would be better if you add your js in a file and include that file in your module / component.  Add script like this  `JHtml::script(JURI::root() . 'components/com_abc/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'); `

Comment: No i have requirement  want to inline include.